# Determine all $ α \in \mathbb{R} $ for which every solution of $ y'' − (2 α − 1) y' + α (α − 1) y = 0 $ tends to $ 0 $ as $ t \to \infty $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem.** Determine all values of $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ for which every
>     solution of
>     $$
>   y'' − (2 \alpha − 1) y' + \alpha (\alpha − 1) y = 0
>   $$
>     tends to $ 0 $ as $ t \to \infty $.

[image: Problem]
[image: Attempted solution]

Comment: all solutions are given by $$c_1 e^{(\alpha -1) t}+c_2 e^{\alpha  t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve:

$$\text{y}''\left(t\right)−\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(t\right)+\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(t\right)=0$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{y}''\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}−\mathcal{L}_t\left[\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}+\mathcal{L}_t\left[\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}$$

Now, use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{y}''\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\text{s}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'\left(0\right)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{y}'\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\left(\text{s}\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)\right)$$
3. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{y}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=0$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)-\text{y}'\left(0\right)-\left(2\cdot\alpha−1\right)\cdot\left(\text{s}\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)\right)+\alpha\cdot\left(\alpha−1\right)\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=0$$

Solving $\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)$:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{y}'\left(0\right)+\text{y}\left(0\right)\cdot\left(1-2\cdot\alpha+\text{s}\right)}{\left(\alpha-\text{s}\right)\cdot\left(\alpha-1-\text{s}\right)}$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, gives us:

$$\text{y}\left(t\right)=e^{t\cdot\left(\alpha-1\right)}\cdot\left(e^t\cdot\left(\text{y}\left(0\right)+\text{y}'\left(0\right)\right)-\alpha\cdot\text{y}\left(0\right)\cdot\left(e^t-1\right)-\text{y}'\left(0\right)\right)$$

Comment: we did not cover Laplace